# A sequence and series problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Assume $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots \ge a_n \ge \ldots \ge 0$ and the sequence $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \epsilon_k$ is convergent where $\epsilon_k = \pm 1$. Prove that $\lim_n a_n \sum_{k=1}^n \epsilon_k \to 0$.

This problem is from the book *Problems in Real Analysis* by Titu Andreescu.

I was trying this problem but couldn't get  a satisfactory solution to it. At first I though that the sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ is convergent and then thought to apply alternating test but realized it cannot be done as the sequence is not always alternating. Please help me do this problem.

Comment: The sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ does converge to $0$. Let $L=\lim_ns_n$. Fix $\epsilon>0$; there is an $n_\epsilon\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $|s_n-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge n_\epsilon$. This implies that $|s_n-s_m|<2\epsilon$ whenever $n,m\ge n_\epsilon$ an hence that $$\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^na_k\epsilon_k\right|<2\epsilon$$ whenever $n_\epsilon\le m<n$. In particular, $|a_{m+1}|=|a_{m+1}\epsilon_{m+1}|<2\epsilon$ for all $m\ge n_\epsilon$. Thus, $\lim_na_n=0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : If you post your comment as an answer, we could vote it up!

Comment: @JohnBentin: Done!

Comment: Closing this question at all suggests a serious lack of experience with students in the real world. I’ll not even give my opinion of doing so months after it was asked and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ does converge to $0$. Let $L=\lim_n s_n$. Fix $\epsilon>0$; there is an $n_\epsilon\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $|s_n-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge n_\epsilon$. This implies that $|s_n-s_m|<2\epsilon$ whenever $n,m\ge n_\epsilon$, and hence that

$$\left|\sum_{k=m+1}na_k\epsilon_k\right|<2\epsilon$$

whenever $n_\epsilon\le m<n$. In particular, $|a_{m+1}|=|a_{m+1}\epsilon_{m+1}|<2\epsilon$ for all $m\ge n_\epsilon$. Thus, $\lim_na_n=0$.